# 'AuthorizationRule' is a type and cannot be used as an expression

Tags: asp.net

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" MasterPageFile="~/4guys.master" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Configuration" %>

<script runat="server">
    Private Const VirtualImageRoot As String = "~/"
Private selectedFolderName As String

Private Sub Page_Init()
    UserRoles.DataSource = Roles.GetAllRoles()
    UserRoles.DataBind()

    UserList.DataSource = Membership.GetAllUsers()
    UserList.DataBind()

    If IsPostBack Then
        selectedFolderName = ""
    Else
        selectedFolderName = Request.QueryString("selectedFolderName")
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Page_Load()
            'Interaction.MsgBox("Welcome");

    If User.IsInRole("Administrator") Then
    Else
        Response.Redirect("~/homepage_aspx/homepage.aspx")
    End If
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        PopulateTree()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Page_PreRender()


    If FolderTree.SelectedNode IsNot Nothing Then
        DisplayAccessRules(FolderTree.SelectedValue)
        SecurityInfoSection.Visible = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub PopulateTree()


    ' Populate the tree based on the subfolders of the specified VirtualImageRoot
    Dim rootFolder As New DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath(VirtualImageRoot))
    Dim root As TreeNode = AddNodeAndDescendents(rootFolder, Nothing)
    FolderTree.Nodes.Add(root)
    Try
        FolderTree.SelectedNode.ImageUrl = "/Simple/i/target.gif"
    Catch
    End Try
End Sub

Private Function AddNodeAndDescendents(folder As DirectoryInfo, parentNode As TreeNode) As TreeNode

    ' Add the TreeNode, displaying the folder's name and storing the full path to the folder as the value...

    Dim virtualFolderPath As String
    If parentNode Is Nothing Then
        virtualFolderPath = VirtualImageRoot
    Else
        virtualFolderPath = parentNode.Value + folder.Name + "/"
    End If

    Dim node As New TreeNode(folder.Name, virtualFolderPath)
    node.Selected = (folder.Name = selectedFolderName)

    ' Recurse through this folder's subfolders
    Dim subFolders As DirectoryInfo() = folder.GetDirectories()
    For Each subFolder As DirectoryInfo In subFolders
        If subFolder.Name <> "_controls" AndAlso subFolder.Name <> "App_Data" Then
            Dim child As TreeNode = AddNodeAndDescendents(subFolder, node)
            node.ChildNodes.Add(child)
        End If
    Next
    Return node
    ' Return the new TreeNode
End Function

Protected Sub FolderTree_SelectedNodeChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)


    ActionDeny.Checked = True
    ActionAllow.Checked = False
    ApplyRole.Checked = True
    ApplyUser.Checked = False
    ApplyAllUsers.Checked = False
    ApplyAnonUser.Checked = False
    UserRoles.SelectedIndex = 0
    UserList.SelectedIndex = 0

    RuleCreationError.Visible = False

    ResetFolderImageUrls(FolderTree.Nodes(0))
    ' Restore previously selected folder's ImageUrl.
    FolderTree.SelectedNode.ImageUrl = "/Simple/i/target.gif"
    ' Set the newly selected folder's ImageUrl.
End Sub

Private Sub ResetFolderImageUrls(parentNode As TreeNode)



    parentNode.ImageUrl = "/Simple/i/folder.gif"

    ' Recurse through this node's child nodes.
    Dim nodes As TreeNodeCollection = parentNode.ChildNodes
    For Each childNode As TreeNode In nodes
        ResetFolderImageUrls(childNode)
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub DisplayAccessRules(virtualFolderPath As String)
    If Not virtualFolderPath.StartsWith(VirtualImageRoot) OrElse virtualFolderPath.IndexOf("..") >= 0 Then


        Throw New ApplicationException("An attempt to access a folder outside of the website directory has been detected and blocked.")
    End If
    Dim config As Configuration = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(virtualFolderPath)
    Dim systemWeb As SystemWebSectionGroup = DirectCast(config.GetSectionGroup("system.web"), SystemWebSectionGroup)
    Dim authorizationRules As AuthorizationRuleCollection = systemWeb.Authorization.Rules
    RulesGrid.DataSource = authorizationRules
    RulesGrid.DataBind()

    TitleOne.InnerText = "Rules applied to " + virtualFolderPath
    TitleTwo.InnerText = "Create new rule for " + virtualFolderPath
End Sub

Private Sub RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs)
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        Dim rule As AuthorizationRule = DirectCast(e.Row.DataItem, AuthorizationRule)
        If Not rule.ElementInformation.IsPresent Then
            e.Row.Cells(3).Text = "Inherited from higher level"
            e.Row.Cells(4).Text = "Inherited from higher level"
            e.Row.CssClass = "odd"
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Function GetAction(rule As AuthorizationRule) As String
    Return rule.Action.ToString()
End Function
Private Function GetRole(rule As AuthorizationRule) As String
    Return rule.Roles.ToString()
End Function
Private Function GetUser(rule As AuthorizationRule) As String
    Return rule.Users.ToString()
End Function
Private Sub DeleteRule(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)


    Dim button As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button)
    Dim item As GridViewRow = DirectCast(button.Parent.Parent, GridViewRow)
    Dim virtualFolderPath As String = FolderTree.SelectedValue
    Dim config As Configuration = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(virtualFolderPath)
    Dim systemWeb As SystemWebSectionGroup = DirectCast(config.GetSectionGroup("system.web"), SystemWebSectionGroup)
    Dim section As AuthorizationSection = DirectCast(systemWeb.Sections("authorization"), AuthorizationSection)
    section.Rules.RemoveAt(item.RowIndex)
    config.Save()
End Sub
Private Sub MoveUp(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    MoveRule(sender, e, "up")
End Sub
Private Sub MoveDown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    MoveRule(sender, e, "down")
End Sub

Private Sub MoveRule(sender As Object, e As EventArgs, upOrDown As String)


    upOrDown = upOrDown.ToLower()

    If upOrDown = "up" OrElse upOrDown = "down" Then
        Dim button As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button)
        Dim item As GridViewRow = DirectCast(button.Parent.Parent, GridViewRow)
        Dim selectedIndex As Integer = item.RowIndex
        If (selectedIndex > 0 AndAlso upOrDown = "up") OrElse (upOrDown = "down") Then
            Dim virtualFolderPath As String = FolderTree.SelectedValue
            Dim config As Configuration = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(virtualFolderPath)
            Dim systemWeb As SystemWebSectionGroup = DirectCast(config.GetSectionGroup("system.web"), SystemWebSectionGroup)
            Dim section As AuthorizationSection = DirectCast(systemWeb.Sections("authorization"), AuthorizationSection)

            ' Pull the local rules out of the authorization section, deleting them from same:
            Dim rulesArray As ArrayList = PullLocalRulesOutOfAuthorizationSection(section)
            If upOrDown = "up" Then
                LoadRulesInNewOrder(section, rulesArray, selectedIndex, upOrDown)
            ElseIf upOrDown = "down" Then
                If selectedIndex < rulesArray.Count - 1 Then
                    LoadRulesInNewOrder(section, rulesArray, selectedIndex, upOrDown)
                Else
                    ' DOWN button in last row was pressed. Load the rules array back in without resorting.
                    For x As Integer = 0 To rulesArray.Count - 1
                        section.Rules.Add(DirectCast(rulesArray(x), AuthorizationRule))
                    Next
                End If
            End If
            config.Save()
        End If
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub LoadRulesInNewOrder(section As AuthorizationSection, rulesArray As ArrayList, selectedIndex As Integer, upOrDown As String)



    AddFirstGroupOfRules(section, rulesArray, selectedIndex, upOrDown)
    AddTheTwoSwappedRules(section, rulesArray, selectedIndex, upOrDown)
    AddFinalGroupOfRules(section, rulesArray, selectedIndex, upOrDown)
End Sub
Private Sub AddFirstGroupOfRules(section As AuthorizationSection, rulesArray As ArrayList, selectedIndex As Integer, upOrDown As String)
    Dim adj As Integer
    If upOrDown = "up" Then
        adj = 1
    Else
        adj = 0
    End If
    For x As Integer = 0 To selectedIndex - adj - 1
        section.Rules.Add(DirectCast(rulesArray(x), AuthorizationRule))
    Next
End Sub
Private Sub AddTheTwoSwappedRules(section As AuthorizationSection, rulesArray As ArrayList, selectedIndex As Integer, upOrDown As String)
    If upOrDown = "up" Then
        section.Rules.Add(DirectCast(rulesArray(selectedIndex), AuthorizationRule))
        section.Rules.Add(DirectCast(rulesArray(selectedIndex - 1), AuthorizationRule))
    ElseIf upOrDown = "down" Then
        section.Rules.Add(DirectCast(rulesArray(selectedIndex + 1), AuthorizationRule))
        section.Rules.Add(DirectCast(rulesArray(selectedIndex), AuthorizationRule))
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub AddFinalGroupOfRules(section As AuthorizationSection, rulesArray As ArrayList, selectedIndex As Integer, upOrDown As String)
    Dim adj As Integer
    If upOrDown = "up" Then
        adj = 1
    Else
        adj = 2
    End If
    For x As Integer = selectedIndex + adj To rulesArray.Count - 1
        section.Rules.Add(DirectCast(rulesArray(x), AuthorizationRule))
    Next

End Sub
Private Function PullLocalRulesOutOfAuthorizationSection(section As AuthorizationSection) As ArrayList

    ' First load the local rules into an ArrayList.

    Dim rulesArray As New ArrayList()
    For Each rule As AuthorizationRule In section.Rules
        If rule.ElementInformation.IsPresent Then
            rulesArray.Add(rule)
        End If
    Next

    ' Next delete the rules from the section.
    For Each rule As AuthorizationRule In rulesArray
        section.Rules.Remove(rule)
    Next
    Return rulesArray
End Function

Private Sub CreateRule(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim newRule As AuthorizationRule
    If ActionAllow.Checked Then
        newRule = New AuthorizationRule(AuthorizationRuleAction.Allow)
    Else
        newRule = New AuthorizationRule(AuthorizationRuleAction.Deny)
    End If

    If ApplyRole.Checked AndAlso UserRoles.SelectedIndex > 0 Then
        newRule.Roles.Add(UserRoles.Text)
        AddRule(newRule)
    ElseIf ApplyUser.Checked AndAlso UserList.SelectedIndex > 0 Then
        newRule.Users.Add(UserList.Text)
        AddRule(newRule)
    ElseIf ApplyAllUsers.Checked Then
        newRule.Users.Add("*")
        AddRule(newRule)
    ElseIf ApplyAnonUser.Checked Then
        newRule.Users.Add("?")
        AddRule(newRule)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub AddRule(newRule As AuthorizationRule)
    Dim virtualFolderPath As String = FolderTree.SelectedValue
    Dim config As Configuration = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(virtualFolderPath)
    Dim systemWeb As SystemWebSectionGroup = DirectCast(config.GetSectionGroup("system.web"), SystemWebSectionGroup)
    Dim section As AuthorizationSection = DirectCast(systemWeb.Sections("authorization"), AuthorizationSection)
    section.Rules.Add(newRule)
    Try
        config.Save()
        RuleCreationError.Visible = False
    Catch ex As Exception
        RuleCreationError.Visible = True
        RuleCreationError.Text = "<div class=""alert""><br />An error occurred and the rule was not added. I saw this happen during testing when I attempted to create a rule that the ASP.NET infrastructure realized was redundant. Specifically, I had the rule <i>DENY ALL USERS</i> in one folder, then attempted to add the same rule in a subfolder, which caused ASP.NET to throw an exception.<br /><br />Here's the error message that was thrown just now:<br /><br /><i>" + ex.Message + "</i></div>"
    End Try
End Sub



</script>



<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="c" Runat="Server">

<!-- #include file="_nav.aspx -->

<table class="webparts">
<tr>
    <th>Website Access Rules</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="details" valign="top">
        <p>
        Use this page to manage access rules for your Web site. Rules are applied to folders, thus providing robust folder-level security enforced by the ASP.NET infrastructure. Rules are persisted as XML in each folder's Web.config file. <i>Page-level security and inner-page security are not handled using this tool &mdash; they are handled using specialized code that is available to the Web Developers.</i>
        </p>



        <table>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top" style="padding-right: 30px;">
                <div class="treeview">
                <asp:TreeView runat="server" ID="FolderTree"
                    OnSelectedNodeChanged="FolderTree_SelectedNodeChanged">
                    <RootNodeStyle ImageUrl="/Simple/i/folder.gif" />
                    <ParentNodeStyle ImageUrl="/Simple/i/folder.gif" />
                    <LeafNodeStyle ImageUrl="/Simple/i/folder.gif" />
                    <SelectedNodeStyle Font-Underline="true" ForeColor="#A21818" />
                </asp:TreeView>
                </div> 
            </td>

            <td valign="top" style="padding-left: 30px; border-left: 1px solid #999;">
            <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="SecurityInfoSection" Visible="false">
                <h2 runat="server" id="TitleOne" class="alert"></h2>

                <p>
                Rules are applied in order. The first rule that matches applies, and the permission in each rule overrides the permissions in all following rules. Use the Move Up and Move Down buttons to change the order of the selected rule. Rules that appear dimmed are inherited from the parent and cannot be changed at this level. 
                </p>

                <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="RulesGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                CssClass="list" GridLines="none"
                OnRowDataBound="RowDataBound"
                >
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <!--response.write(GetAction((AuthorizationRule)Container.DataItem))-->

                                **<%#GetAction((AuthorizationRule), Container.DataItem)%>**
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Roles">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                            <!--    response.write(GetRole((AuthorizationRule)Container.DataItem))-->
                                **<%# GetRole((AuthorizationRule),Container.DataItem) %>**
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="User">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                            <!--    response.write(GetUser((AuthorizationRule)Container.DataItem))-->
                                **<%#GetUser((AuthorizationRule), Container.DataItem)%>**
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete Rule">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Delete Rule" CommandArgument="<%# (AuthorizationRule)Container.DataItem %>" OnClick="DeleteRule" OnClientClick="return confirm('Click OK to delete this rule.')" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Move Rule">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="  Up  " CommandArgument="<%# (AuthorizationRule)Container.DataItem %>" OnClick="MoveUp" />
                                <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" Text="Down" CommandArgument="<%# (AuthorizationRule)Container.DataItem %>" OnClick="MoveDown" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>

                <br />
                <hr />
                <h2 runat="server" id="TitleTwo" class="alert"></h2>
                <b>Action:</b>
                <asp:RadioButton runat="server" ID="ActionDeny" GroupName="action" 
                    Text="Deny" Checked="true" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <asp:RadioButton runat="server" ID="ActionAllow" GroupName="action" 
                    Text="Allow" />

                <br /><br />
                <b>Rule applies to:</b>
                <br />
                <asp:RadioButton runat="server" ID="ApplyRole" GroupName="applyto"
                    Text="This Role:" Checked="true" />
                <asp:DropDownList ID="UserRoles" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
                <asp:ListItem>Select Role</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <br />

                <asp:RadioButton runat="server" ID="ApplyUser" GroupName="applyto"
                    Text="This User:" />
                <asp:DropDownList ID="UserList" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
                <asp:ListItem>Select User</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList> 
                <br />


                <asp:RadioButton runat="server" ID="ApplyAllUsers" GroupName="applyto"
                    Text="All Users (*)"  />
                <br />


                <asp:RadioButton runat="server" ID="ApplyAnonUser" GroupName="applyto"
                    Text="Anonymous Users (?)"  />
                <br /><br />

                <asp:Button ID="Button4" runat="server" Text="Create Rule" OnClick="CreateRule"
                    OnClientClick="return confirm('Click OK to create this rule.');" />

                <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="RuleCreationError"></asp:Literal>
            </asp:Panel>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>


</asp:Content>
```

'AuthorizationRule' is a type and cannot be used as an expression.
errors are bold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some places of your markup you have an unnecessary `,` (line no. 352, 358 and 364)

stuff like

```
 <%#GetAction((AuthorizationRule), Container.DataItem)%>
```

I think, should be

```
  <%#GetAction(DirectCast(Container.DataItem, AuthorizationRule))%>
```

similarly

```
<%#GetRole(CType(Container.DataItem, AuthorizationRule))%>
```

and

```
<%#GetUser(DirectCast(Container.DataItem, AuthorizationRule))%>
```

Also use this replacing what you have

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Delete Rule" CommandArgument='<%# DirectCast(Container.DataItem, AuthorizationRule) %>' OnClick="DeleteRule" OnClientClick="return confirm('Click OK to delete this rule.')" />
```

and

```
 <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="  Up  " CommandArgument='<%# DirectCast(Container.DataItem, AuthorizationRule) %>' OnClick="MoveUp" />
 <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" Text="Down" CommandArgument='<%# DirectCast(Container.DataItem, AuthorizationRule) %>' OnClick="MoveDown" />
```

Comment: if i do not use comma "," it says Error 11 Comma, ')', or a valid expression continuation expected.

Comment: Just try running after you fix these.